# Limiting feature class parameter to specific geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I have a tool that will update the geometry of a feature class based on the geometry of another, using a common identifier.

It works great but the way I have it set up, you have to first select the gdb holding the two feature classes, then select each feature class.

Is there a way, once the gdb (which defines the workspace) is selected, to then limit the options for the two feature class parameters to those found in the selected gdb?

When I run it, I know they have to be in the same gdb, but I'd like to share it with colleagues as a tool and I'd like it to be at least a little fool-proof, considering it was fool-made.

Here's the code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
UpdateData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
UpdateField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
ProjectData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
ProjectField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

geometries = {key:value for (key,value) in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(UpdateData, [UpdateField, 'SHAPE@'])}

notfound = []

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ProjectData, [ProjectField, 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            row[1] = geometries[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        except:
            notfound.append(row[0])
```

[image: GUI Screenshot]

Comment: It's been a very long time since I worked on an arcpy tool so I cannot provide a specific answer, but you may want to try using a tool validation script, which can execute blocks of Python code when the user changes based on user input: (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/customizing-script-tool-behavior.htm)

I think this code needs to go INTO a .tbx file, which means you can't see or edit it unless you open it up in ArcMap itself. A working example of this is in a toolbox I made here: https://github.com/iboates/raster_stamp, so maybe you can explore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would create a list of the feature classes in the selected gdb and insert it in a dropdown menu within your toolbox.

To create the list of featureclasses you can use [`arcpy.ListFeatureClasses`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) to create the list (check the link for options like wildcard or FC type if you want to limit your results).

Then, if you want a parameter to be able to handle a list of values rather than just one value, [set the MultiValue property to Yes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm#GUID-9E1F9F7C-7327-469B-9748-B4B3DBF3736E).

[image]

Then, as @wfgeo suggested, to inser a dropdown in your toolbox, go in the Validation tab in the properties of your script from ArcCatalog and change the `def updateParameters(self):` to something like (not tested, surely tou need to adjust it a little):

```
def updateParameters(self):
    # If database has been set
    if self.params[0]:
        # set list with values to choose from for UpdateData variable
        self.params[1].filter.list = # your list created with ListFeatureClasses goes here
        # set list with values to choose from for ProjectData variable
        self.params[3].filter.list = # your list created with ListFeatureClasses goes here
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a shot. I'm pretty new to building tools like this, so I'll have to do some playing around. I'd imagine I can read the FC type of the first feature class and use that as a filter when they select the second, to make sure they are the same?

Comment: Of course. You can do that with the [`Describe`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm) function on the FC like `desc = arcpy.Describe("your/fc/here")` `desc.shapeType # return e.g. "Polygon" (String)` and build another list of FC with the same ListFeatureClasses passing the shapeType to its feature_type param.

Comment: You're very welcome. If my answer solved your issue, please feel free to mark it as accepted, otherwise tell me if you need more info.

Comment: Oof. Didn't even see that option. There you go. Thanks again.